# I can't do dragon shouts

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can't do dragon shouts. I asked my friend and she said that it might be a glitch.

I don't know what to do, the game told me to go to some place - I don't remember the exact name, but I remember that it was ''Grey..'' something and that it was on a top of a mountain and that it was thousands of stairs to get up there. Do I need more dragon souls?

Comment: Why is he getting downvoted?

Comment: @jmfsg, He says he asked a friend about it and he doesn't know what to do else. Not everyone knows how to look for this kind of info on the net. Also, his question can easily be salvaged through editing, I'd do it myself if it wasn't so long ago since I last played Skyrim.

Comment: It seems to me that you're not a true Dovahkiin.

Comment: Or maybe he's just at work and he can't hit the websites that google would bring up that would answer his question (yet oddly enough he can hit this one... ) - true story, I can.

Answer (score 7):

Following the main quest, you should be able to shout once you kill the dragon that attacks Whiterun after you complete Bleak Falls Barrow. You should *not* need to complete the next stage of the main quest, climbing the Seven Thousand Steps to High Hrothgar, to shout (though doing that next stage should teach you an additional shout).

Make sure when you go into the shouts section of the magic menu that Unrelenting Force is selected; that's probably the only shout you know, so if you de-select it pressing the shout button won't do anything.